# Parent DIV isn't expanding to fit all of the content

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a million times, but after looking through a ton of posts, I can't find an answer.

Here's my code:

```css
.feedCard {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 227px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  width: 78%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 115px;
}
.facebookPost {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.postContent {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
.postLabel {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.postLabel a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.postStamp {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: right;
}
.postTextHolder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 11px;
}
.postText {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.feedPostUserIcon {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedCard">
  <div class="facebookPost">
    <span title="view on facebook" class="postLabel"><a href="facebook.com">facebook</a></span>
    <span class="postStamp">Posted at 11:42 AM on 1/18/17</span>

    <div class="postContent">
      <div class="postTextHolder">
        <img class="feedPostUserIcon" src="images/image.png">
        <span class="postText">filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main DIV is sitting at it's minimum height setting and not expanding to fit the extra text.

Side question: Is there a way to make the wrapped text look nicer? It seems to get really close up to the image and it looks awful. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please qualify what you mean by main `div`. Is it the `.feedCard`? `.facebookPost`?

Comment: for your side question, you should be able to add either a `margin-right` to the `<img>` or a `margin-left` to the span (I think, haven't tested)

Comment: You got it. I'm glad StackOverflow exists so I can rack my brain for two hours, then post a question, then immediately answer my own question, and afterward get my side question answered with something super simple. TL;DR I'm dumb, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I hate myself.

I had the "post content" DIV inside the "facebook post" DIV when it should have been below it.

Here's the fixed code for reference:

```
            <div class="feedCard">
                <div class="facebookPost">
                    <span title="view on facebook" class="postLabel"><a href="facebook.com">facebook</a></span>
                    <span class="postStamp">Posted at 11:42 AM on 1/18/17</span>
                </div>
                <div class="postContent">
                    <div class="postTextHolder">
                        <img class="feedPostUserIcon" src="images/image.png">
                        <span class="postText"> ... </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```